# Run reports/send emails from a list of parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, sqlparameter

I've run into a problem that, although I feel in my gut there is a 'simple' resolution, I'm not getting anywhere with it! The reports I'm running are using a dataset that includes a username that I need to use to 1) Use as a parameter for running the report and 2) Use to create an email address and send it to the user. I really don't know enough yet about SSRS, or have the experience, to have already created the parameterized report (nevermind the iterating through the dataset that I'm assuming will be needed), nor have I ever set up a data-driven subscription. ANY help on either of these issues would earn eternal gratitude.

Thank you all....again!

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Its not too bad once you've been through it once.  First you need to get the SQL out of your parameter dataset (it's redundant in the report definition). Then in Report Manager/SharePoint you can define the Data Driven Subscription.  Paste in the SQL from your parameter dataset into the wizard as the Query, and then use the columns from that SELECT on the later pages of the wizard as required e.g. email address for ... email address.

No coding is required (beyond the parameter dataset which you already have) and the wizard is fairly self-explanatory and well documented.

Good luck!

Mike